# Why did God curse Canaan?

Tags: genesis

Gen 9:22(Kjv)   And Ham, the father of Canaan, saw the nakedness of his father, and told his two brethren without.

23  And Shem and Japheth took a garment, and laid it upon both their shoulders, and went backward, and covered the nakedness of their father; and their faces were backward, and they saw not their father's nakedness.

24  And Noah awoke from his wine, and knew what his younger son had done unto him.

25  And he said, *Cursed be Canaan*;a servant of servants shall he be unto his brethren.

Why did God curse Cannan  instead of his father

Answer (score 0):

When the incident takes place, all four of Ham's sons are already born. Pronouncing the curse upon Canaan narrows the parameters of the curse to only one line of Ham's descendants. It was not uncommon for the curse of a father's sins to be passed down through the extended line of succeeding generations until the fourth generation. In the case of Ham, God is being quite merciful in the limitations of this curse to a single line of descendants.

> *"The Lord visits the iniquity of the fathers on the children and the children’s children, to the third and the fourth generation."*
>   Ex 34:6-7, Deut 5:8-10.

The fact that God restricted the curse only to the line of Canaan did not subject the other sons of Ham to the same curse because of the sin of their father

Comment: That’s an interesting hypothesis, supporting documentation would be greatly appreciated. I am not of this view, I am of the view that Canaan had from his non Tamaiym mother inherited corrupted DNA (seed) that came from the sons of God of Genesis 6, reason why the flood was sent to purge this DNA. Desperate to have a non contaminated child Ham tried to sleep with his own mother. Had it not been for Canaan Ham would never have considered this desperate move. But given this is a duplicate question I won’t be responding. Looking forward to your sources though. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting, what documentation could you provide that would support this view?

Comment: Yes, can you support what you say with scripture reference, please. I have up-voted as this is interesting but at the moment it is opinion without valid supoort.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for, or did you have a different question?  "The Lord visits the iniquity of the fathers on the children and the children’s children, to the third and the fourth generation." Ex 34:6-7, Deut 5:8-10, The fact that God restricted the curse only to the line of Canaan did not subject the other sons of Ham to the same curse because of the sin of their father.

Comment: I can support this entirely with Scripture from the Hebrew

Comment: I have not voted yet waiting for collaborating sources

Comment: The question OP asked was why did god limit it to just one line Canaan’s? You haven’t actually addressed that point except to say that God was merciful. This actually goes against the very verse you are quoting that says to the children plural.